# non-smooth and noisy curve in addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

The output is attached. One can see the curve is noisy and nonsmooth. Where must modify?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
‎\usepackage{pgfplots}‎‎‎
‎\‎pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}‎
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.‎0‎]‎‎
‎\begin{axis}[%‎‎
    ,‎axis line style = thick‎
    ,‎domain=‎0‎‎:1‎
    ,‎samples=‎3‎0‎0‎
    ,‎axis lines=middle‎
    ,‎enlargelimits=true‎
    ‎‎,‎xtick={‎0‎‎‎,‎‎‎1}‎
   ‎‎ ‎‎‎,ytick={‎-‎0.‎0‎1‎‎‎‎‎‎‎,‎0.‎0‎1‎‎‎‎‎‎‎},‎‎‎‎‎ 
   ‎‎‎ ]
    ‎‎‎\addplot[‎smooth‎‎,thick‎, ‎color = ‎black‎‎] {exp(2*x)-1.0012‎-‎1.9380*x‎-‎2.4808*x^2‎-‎0.0782*x^3‎-‎1.8891*x^4‎‎};‎    

‎\end{axis}‎‎ 
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎‎‎

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of you have a ton of hidden unicode charts in this MWE, U+200E all over the place, so for me this mwe fails right away, cannot compile. You might want to clean that up.

Comment: This tool can help you find these hidden chars: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

Comment: Since the numbers are so small, pdflatex might have issues with precision. Switching to lualatex helps.

Comment: thanks, however, how do I do?

Comment: @daleif: One has to switch to `compat=1.16` (or similar). With `compat=1.8`, `lualatex` gives incorrect output comparable to the above one.

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not work!

Comment: It could be that you're expecting more of `smooth` than it actually does. It's not like a moving average or filter, so it doesn't really remove noise. What it does is that instead of drawing straight lines between the coordinates, it draws a curve. If you zoom in and make the line thinner (`very thin` instead of `thick`) you can easily see that the plot becomes less jagged with `smooth`.

Comment: I confirm that @MarianG.'s suggestion does work on my updated TeXLive 2019 distribution.